# Where can I find algorithm for determining street by given latitude and longitude?

Tags: gps, reverse-geocoding, openstreetmap

I can't find a description of algorithm which can determine street by given coordinates. I'm using OpenStreetMaps as my map data source. I've found [this](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim) tool which does the job, but the algorithm is not given. Please note that I need the algorithm not the tool itself. And the algorithm may not be specifically designed for OSM. I just need to grasp the idea how the algorithm works.

Thanks for replies
Regards
Gagik

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no mathematical algorithm for determining the street from latitude and longitude.

Every street has to be put in a database, along with a series of latitude and longitude points.  I'd guess that each latitude and longitude point would be about 50 meters apart down the center of the road.

Once all of this information is put in a database, the "algorithm" is select the street where the given latitude and longitude is closest to one of the latitude and longitude points in the series, and return the street name.